# verify passwords encrypted in c# from coldfusion

Tags: c#, .net, coldfusion

I need to decrypt (or encrypt original in the same way, whatever is easiest) passwords encrypted in C# by a user defined function in Coldfusion. Below is the c# function used

```
private static byte[] key = { };
private static byte[] IV = { 38, 55, 206, 48, 28, 64, 20, 16 };
private static string stringKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

public static string Md5Encrypt(string password)
{
  string empty = string.Empty;
  string str;
  try
  {
    Helpers.key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Helpers.stringKey.Substring(0, 8));
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password.ToString());
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream) memoryStream, cryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(Helpers.key, Helpers.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    str = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray()).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return "";
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: What does that function look like in ColdFusion? What do they use and what specifically is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I need to verify passwords in coldfusion that were encrypted in c# by this function. There is no coldfusion function yet.

Comment: Ok, what specifically is not working?

Comment: passwords should NEVER be encrypted. they should be hashed. Encrypted passwords are a HUGE liability and can easily be decrypted if the encrypted data is obtained by a hacker or by a database admin or developer.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this IV = { 38, 55, 206, 48, 28, 64, 20, 16 } integrated

Comment: @CarCar I did'nt write the .net application, I just have to use the same database in my coldfusion app

Comment: Please include the ColdFusion code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm trying to encrypt in in the same way using coldfusion so I can compare the encrypted values: encrypt(toBase64("password"),toBase64("key"),"DES","Base64")

Comment: I agree with @CarCar - convince whoever is in charge to bite the bullet and hash the passwords instead of encrypting them.

Comment: I will throw in one more agreement here. When it comes to storing passwords, "Because it was done that way before." isn't a valid reason to keep doing it. When your database is breached, nobody will care how it was done before. The fingers will be pointing at the current developer. If you _have_to store passwords, hash; don't encrypt.

Comment: I will also point out that your function has a bit of a wonky name. `MD5`, despite being extremely insecure, isn't encryption. It is hashing. But very broken hashing. And inside your function, it's using `DESCryptoServiceProvider`, which is a C# implementation of DES _encryption_, not hashing, but is also somewhat weak and broken. You have original data that you need to decrypt? You'd have to step through specifically what the C# implementation is doing at each step so that you have the same inputs.

Comment: What sort of data is the login protecting? Is there PII or other sensitive data? How many users are there? Is this a public-facing app or an intranet app? Don't answer those here, but it should give you an idea of how disruptive you can be to your users, and this _will_ likely be a disruptive process. If these are internal users and there are only a few hundred of them, it might be easiest to just expire everyone's login and make them generate a new password, then store the hashed value properly. (See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Comment: NOTE: Only **one** person should ever be able to know the password: the person who entered it. There shouldn't be a "Recover My Password" link; it should be a "Reset My Password" link (which may be what you need to implement anyway). Don't forget to properly use a salt. Login is a _much_ more complex topic than it initially seems and unfortunately there are too many examples of apps that didn't pay enough attention to their login system. https://haveibeenpwned.com/ https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10

Comment: Maybe the password is needed to access 3rd party services and is therefore needed in the C# and the CF applicaton, as well.